# What's the right way to stream a file and write it?

Tags: node.js

I need to stream a file and get its data, then save it. Here's my simple test-case:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/image.jpg');

let fileData = '';
fileReadStream.on('data', function(data) {
  fileData += data;
});

fileReadStream.on('end', () => {
  fs.writeFileSync('/path/to/image_copy.jpg', fileData);
});
```

I would expect that the output file (image_copy.jpg) is simply a copy of image.jpg. However, it's about 1.8x bigger, and not a valid image. Am I missing some kind of encoding somewhere?

Comment: `fileData = ''` and `fileData += data` ... jpgs are not text files (they are not strings).  Push all the chunks (which are Buffers) into `yourArray = []` and then write `Buffer.concat(yourArray)` to the file.  Or better yet, make use of [`pipe`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablepipedestination-options).

Comment: It wasn't me, but the close-voter reason was "not reproducible or was caused by a typo".  My guess is that the down-voter/close-voter thought it is rather careless to concatenate buffers to a string.  You could have easily determined that the type of `data` was a Buffer with a simple `console.log(data)`.   You could have determined what was going on with the output by examining the contents of the file.  Perhaps you were too quick to try "searching for it" rather than doing some basic debugging to gather clues.  You also didn't describe the contents of the (obviously wrong) file.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't a typo, but rather a newbie issue on my part - I didn't know how to handle buffers correctly. Your solution works perfectly - would you like to post it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *stream a file and write it* is what `pipe` is for.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const readable = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/image.jpg');
const writable = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/image_copy.jpg');

readable.pipe(writable);
```

#### If you need the entire file in memory...

You can concatenate the buffers like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/image.jpg');

const chunks = [];
fileReadStream.on('data', function(data) {
  chunks.push(data);
});

fileReadStream.on('end', () => {
  const fileData = Buffer.concat(chunks);
  fs.writeFileSync('/path/to/image_copy.jpg', fileData);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the same solution you suggested in the comment. Please see my answer in the comment in response to Tech Savvy about why I need to deal with the whole file object in one go.